# Artin exercise 2.1.8

Tags: matrices, proof-explanation

I'm trying to solve the below exercise in Artin.

> Given an example of $2 \times 2$ matrices such that $A^{-1} B \neq BA^{-1}$.

I don't have intuition for how to get started, and while I could try a number of different matrices, I'd like to be more systematic. The only insight I've been able to come to is:
$$
A^{-1} B \neq BA^{-1} \iff B \neq ABA^{-1} \iff BA \neq AB.
$$
So I need $A$ and $B$ to not commute, $A$ must be invertible, and $B$ may not be. The standard example in Artin in the $2 \times 2$ case of matrix multiplication not being commutative doesn't work (using matrix units) because both of those matrices have determinant $0$.

Could someone give me a hint on how I can approach this problem systematically?

Comment: Consider a rotation composed with a reflection.

Comment: To be honest, any two random matrices that you write will probably not commute

Answer (score 1):

Hint : You may know two matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 \\
   \end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 \\
   \end{pmatrix}$ are not commute. What can you do next?

> $A+I=X$ and $B+I=Y$ are both invertible, and by calculation, it is easy to show following is truth: $$XY=(A+I)(B+I)=AB+A+B+I\ne BA+B+A+I=(B+I)(A+I)=YX$$